# How to create/write to an array in the same structure MySQL does

Tags: javascript, mysql

What is the best way to essentially copy an array that was created with MySQL.

So if the database has 2 columns and 2 rows the array created from the query would be

Created from SQL query:

```
array[index].id
array[index].name
```

is there a way i can copy this array  and data to an identical structure that will enable me to interact with it the same way.

Created with JavaScript:

```
new_array[index].id
new_array[index].name
```

Comment: In Javascript you can create an array of objects, for example: `new_array = [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 2, name:"B"}]`. Then you can do, `new_array[0].id // output: 1` or `new_array[1].name // output: "B"`.